# DNS for REST API in machines with different resources

Tags: domain-name-system

Suppose I have a REST API system that has these requirements:

```
The API that can be accessed via this URL http://<ipaddress>/api/
I have three computers with three IP addresses: IP A, B and C respectively. 

Each of this computer can be accessed via URL API specified earlier.
to access A the URL is http://<IP A>/api.
to access B the URL is http://<IP B>/api.
to access C the URL is http://<IP C>/api.

Each computer may have different information / resources.
A has resource X
B has resource Y
C has resource Z

Client 1 has access in resource X
Client 2 has access in resource Y
Client 3 has access in resource Z
```

**Question:**
Can I built those three API access in a single URL using a domain name. For instance, http://example/api for those three computers (A, B and C in single URL http://example/api)?

What I know is the DNS may return multiple IPs and the client can pick 1 IP in round robin fashion. However, in this case, A, B and C have different resources. So the client needs to be mapped to a specific machine. For instance, request from client 1 need to be mapped to computer A where the resource X resides.

**Follow-up Question:**
If DNS is not suitable, is there another distributed protocol to implement this kind of system?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you plan to identify your clients?  You have several options - perhaps basic auth, ip address?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices, the simplest one:

Use a DNS record with round robin for example api.yourcompany.com so all clients can access the api through http://api.yourcompany.com/api and due to round robin the access will be more or less balanced. Then for each service X, Y, Z you can create a DNS record like servicex.yourcompany.com, servicey.yourcompany.com ... using a CNAME pointing to the right server.

As Ian Bamforth stated you can also have a reverse proxy in front of them (nginx, apache, haproxy ...) and redirect to the required services depending on the URL used.

EDIT:

Example configurations for apache

```
<Proxy "balancer://apicluster">
    BalancerMember "http://serverx.yourcompany.com:80"
    BalancerMember "http://servery.yourcompany.com:80"
    BalancerMember "http://serverz.yourcompany.com:80"
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /api/ balancer://apicluster/api/
ProxyPass /servicex/ http://serverx.yourcompany.com/servicex/
ProxyPass /servicex/ http://servery.yourcompany.com/servicey/
ProxyPass /servicex/ http://serverz.yourcompany.com/servicez/
```

This way requests coming to your server with URL /api will be *routed* through the load balancer, URLs /servicex will be *routed* to serverx and so on.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How if X, Y and Z are the same services but the resource/data is different? For some reason, the resource/data can't be aggregated into one and need to be stored separately.

Comment: @yushuzima I edited the answer, I hope this is more clear.

Comment: thanks. it is better now. How if the resource X. Y and Z are moved between computer A, B and C dynamically? Can this technique work? Suppose if the resource is shifted every 5 minutes.

Comment: Then you would need to update your configuration accondingly